# How to slide from one html page to another

Tags: android, html, webview, slider, slide

I am making an android  book app with java using web view and my pages in html.
As I am new to this, I am trying to find how to slide from one page to another.
I found some tutorials on how to use a slider but that is for images and I have no idea how to do it for html pages.
is there a way of doing something like that;

here is a link to the app I made if you want to have a look(its very small for testing purposes, with 3 pages).

https://github.com/Philip2021-Gr/book-app-sliding-between-html-files

Comment: Use ViewPager. Your adapter would create a WebView for each page.

Comment: no idea how to do that , any suggested tutorials? will this method display my html pages stored in assets folder?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: ok, ill post the codes from the two activities that  i have so far for example